# ggplot2 faceting by year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot monthly precipitation data for an eight year long (2004-2011) series with facet_grid to plot monthly values for each year in a single plot. But, as many times, a problem arises when plotting (probably my fault). You can see the plot I get with x axis starting at 2004 and ending at 2011 for each plot but I need the plot to run from january to december for each year/facet. How can I get rid of that error?

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Here you can get the output of dput(pcp.mensual) http://ubuntuone.com/0EZvmwXGnSkqNVwXZOnx8E and following is the code I use (a piece of a longer script).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

system("awk '{ print $1 \";\" $2 \";\" $3 \";\" $5 \";\" $10 \";\" $11 \";\" $13 }' visbel.cor > kk.dat",intern=T)

# Lectura de datos
datos=read.csv("kk.dat",sep=";",header=T,na.strings="-99.900")

# Inclusión de una columna con formato temporal 
# (dato original en formato %y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S)
datos=within(datos, datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(FECHA,H_SOLAR),format = "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))

# Creación del objeto datetime
#datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(datos$FECHA,datos$H_SOLAR),format = "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

# Eliminación de valores NA en Precipitación para barplot
datos$Precipitacion[is.na(datos$Precipitacion)]=0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------

pcp.diaria=aggregate(cbind(Precip.diaria=Precipitacion) ~ FECHA, datos, sum)
pcp.diaria=within(pcp.diaria, date <- as.POSIXct(paste(pcp.diaria$FECHA),format = "%y/%m/%d"))

# Agregación mensual
pcp.diaria$mes <- floor_date(pcp.diaria$date, "month")
pcp.mensual=ddply(pcp.diaria, "mes", summarise, x = sum(Precip.diaria,na.rm=TRUE))
pcp.mensual$ano=year(pcp.mensual$mes)
colnames(pcp.mensual) <- c("mes", "Precip.mensual","ano")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------                            

ggplot(data=pcp.mensual,aes(x=mes, y=Precip.mensual)) +
  facet_grid(ano ~. ) +
  geom_bar(colour="blue",stat="identity",fill="blue") +
```

Comment: Thanks for giving a reproducible example, but fyi almost all of this code is unneccessary - you just needed to give the object and the code for the plot, I think

Comment: Maybe, I just want to give enough information for you to answer. And maybe it helps someone. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: No worries, I only comment because it can be a little overwhelming to work through where the problem is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `months()` function to extract month information from a POSIXct object. You can just have that as your `x` instead of `mes`. To get the months ordered as you want, rather than alphabetically, you can make an ordered factor:

```
pcp.mensual$month <- months(pcp.mensual$mes)
pcp.mensual$month <- factor(pcp.mensual$month, levels = unique(pcp.mensual$month))
ggplot(data=pcp.mensual,aes(x=pcp.mensual$month, y=Precip.mensual)) +
  facet_grid(ano ~. ) +
  geom_bar(colour="blue",stat="identity",fill="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Just a comment, the plot starts on April. It looks strange it is not starting on January, as the data series does.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable issue! See the edit, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Perfect solution, runs great. Now I have to look for `factor` command help to understand. Does it come with base R, lubridate?

Comment: `factor` is base-r, factor is a class of data in R. Have a look at `?factor`